# Use mouse to manually adjust geom_text() position?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

Just wondering if there is any package/functionality to manually manipulate the positioning of text from `geom_text()`? I've been using `ggrepel::geom_repel_text()` for positioning without overlap, which is good for most cases, but when I have a ton of points all clustered in a tight space it would be much easier to just move them around without having to figure out the coordinates associated with each spot. Is this possible?

Comment: There may be some way to do it within R, but I would guess that you're probably best off saving the plot as an SVG file and using a tool like Inkscape to edit it.

Comment: Something with `ggmap::gglocator()` ?

Comment: Great point @Marius, I don't know why I didn't think of that. I have burned a silly amount of hours on this and it would be much easier to edit an SVG file.

Answer (score 3):

In case your problem relates to deciding which points to label, here's a Shiny app which allows for manual selection of points to label in a ggplot. It relies on ggrepel to space them, so if you want manual control, Marius makes a good suggestion.
https://github.com/AliciaSchep/gglabeller